# Does a $\mathbb P^1$ with four embedded points have the same dualizing sheaf as $\mathbb P^1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, duality-theorems

Suppose $X$ is a $\mathbb P^1$ with four distinct embedded points, looking locally like $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C[x,y] / (x^2, xy)$. I think a subresult of some work I'm doing would be that the dualizing sheaf of $X$ is just $i_* \mathcal O(-2)$, where $i: \mathbb P^1 \hookrightarrow X$ is the reduction of $X$.

I would like a reality check to see if this is actually known to be true? Or can that not be?

Comment: What definition of dualizing sheaf are you using?

Comment: @Mohan The Hartshorne one, $Ext(\mathcal O_X, \omega_{\mathbb P^n})$ for some inclusion $X \subset \mathbb P^n$. Or equivalently the dualizing property with the trace map.

Comment: Which ext? Typically you will take the codimension, but if the scheme is not equidimensional or has embedded points, situation is more delicate. Dualizing sheaf with the desired duality properties exists only for Cohen-Macaulay schemes and embedded points thus are a no-no.

Comment: @Mohan Yeah, should be the codimension. Hartshorne III, (7.5) claims that this is indeed the dualizing sheaf on *any* projective scheme, and gives rise to isomorphisms $Hom(F, \omega_X) \cong H^n(X, F)^\vee$. If I understand that stuff correctly, you need equidimensional+CM only for the typical Serre duality $H^i(X, F) = H^{n-i}(X, F^\vee \otimes \omega_X)^\vee$ (7.7).

Comment: Since your scheme is not Cohen-Macaulay, the dualizing complex (which is $\mathcal{E}xt^\bullet(\mathcal{O}_X,\omega_{\Bbb P^n})$ for any projective $X\subset \Bbb P^n$) is not quasi-isomorphic to a complex concentrated in one degree (aka "the dualizing complex is not a sheaf"). Sometimes you can still get some use out of the top homology of this complex, but it depends on your applications. Can you clarify what you want to do?